# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, terminal, rvm, osx-lion, mysql.sock

I am trying to run mysql client on my terminal. I have installed the latest mysql gem.

```
 ➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ ruby -v
    ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
    ➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ rails -v
    Rails 2.3.14
    ➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ which mysql
    mysql: aliased to nocorrect mysql
    ➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ which ruby
    /usr/bin/ruby
    ➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ which rails
    /usr/bin/rails
    ➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.14)
actionpack (2.3.14)
activerecord (2.3.14)
activeresource (2.3.14)
activesupport (2.3.14)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.21)
capistrano (2.9.0)
capybara (0.3.9)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
childprocess (0.2.2)
columnize (0.3.4, 0.3.3)
cucumber (0.9.4)
cucumber-rails (0.3.2)
culerity (0.2.15)
daemons (1.1.4)
database_cleaner (0.6.7)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
expertiza-authlogic (2.1.6.1)
fastercsv (1.5.4)
fastthread (1.0.7)
ffi (1.0.10, 1.0.9)
gdata (1.1.2)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
gherkin (2.2.9)
highline (1.6.2)
hoptoad_notifier (2.4.11)
json (1.4.6)
json_pure (1.6.1)
linecache (0.46)
mime-types (1.16)
mongrel (1.1.5)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.3.7)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.2.1)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
rack (1.1.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (2.3.14)
rake (0.9.2)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.5)
rdoc (3.11)
RedCloth (4.2.8)
rgl (0.4.0)
ruby-debug (0.10.4)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.4)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
selenium-webdriver (2.8.0, 2.7.0)
stream (0.5)
term-ansicolor (1.0.7, 1.0.6)

➜  expertiza git:(master) ✗ sudo su
Password:
sh-3.2# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
sh-3.2#
```

I am not able to get rid of the above error. I have created a `mysql.sock file` in `/Users/HPV/expertiza/tmp/sockets`. In the file I have written `mysql.default_socket =/expertiza/tmp/sockets/mysql.sock`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not supposed to be a file, it's supposed to be a socket.

Comment: Initially there was a empty sockets folder in `/Users/HPV/expertiza/tmp/sockets`. What should I do?

Comment: Leave it alone so it can create sockets there.

Comment: Ok deleted mysql.sock. Error still persists.

Comment: Did you restart mysqld? Did it create a socket?

Comment: It never started only. I ma stuck in the command `sh-3.2# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`. Socket folder is empty

Comment: If the server isn't running, `mysql` will definitely be unable to connect to it! You need to run the server first. (`mysql` is the client, `mysqld` is the server. You should use a script to launch/monitor the server.)

Comment: `sh-3.2# mysqld
111020 20:29:29 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
111020 20:29:29 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

111020 20:29:29 [ERROR] Aborting

111020 20:29:29 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016376/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-homebrew)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to [follow the directions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/osx-installation-pkg.html) to install and start the server.

The command varies depending on how you installed MySQL. Try this first:

> sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start

If that fails:

> cd /usr/local/mysql
>   sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe
>   (Enter your password, if necessary)
>   (Press Control-Z)
>   bg

Comment: The command which starts mysql is **mysqld**, which stands for "mysql daemon".  If your mysql is ever not running, simply type that command into your terminal.  :)

Answer (score 32):

Also, if you got this error and installed mysql via Homebrew, I found that this works (though you need to change "5.6.12" to your own version):

> /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.12/bin/mysql.server restart

I just created a file ~/restartMysql.sh in my home directory (with only the line above in it) so that I can just use this whenever MySQL is acting up

Comment: THIS. SO MUCH THIS. Dude, I love you.

Answer (score 17):

Run the following on the command line :

```
$ mysql.server start
```

Comment: The following error appears: `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.23/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/var/mysql/Victors-MacBook-Air-2.local.err: Permission denied`

Answer (score 5):

this [post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-root@localhost-using-password-no-459578/) helped did it for me, I'll rewrite the steps here (note: i'll be also writing the output of your commands.. just so that you know you're on track)

*first stop the server if running:*

```
[root@servert1 ~]# /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
Stopping MySQL: [ OK ]
```

*run an sql dameon on a separate thread*

```
[root@servert1 ~]# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &    
[1] 13694    
[root@servert1 ~]# Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

*open a separate shell window and type*

```
[root@servert1 ~]# mysql -u root

Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with ; or \g.

Your MySQL connection id is 1

Server version: 5.0.77 Source distribution



Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.
```

*start using mysql*

```
mysql> use mysql; 

Reading table information for completion of table and column names

You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A



Database changed
```

*update the `user` table manually with your new password (note: feel free to type `mysql> show tables;`
 just to get a perspective on where you are)*

NOTE: from MySQL 5.7 passwords are in the `authenication_string` table, so the command is `update user set authentication_string=password('testpass') where user='root';`

```
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("testpass") where User='root';

Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.05 sec)

Rows matched: 3 Changed: 3 Warnings: 0
```

*flush privileges (i'm not sure what this privileges is all about.. but it works)*

```
mysql> flush privileges; 

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)
```

*quit*

```
mysql> quit

Bye
```

*stop the server*

NOTE: on OS X or macOS, `mysql.server` is located at `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/`.

```
mysql.server stop

Shutting down MySQL
.130421 09:27:02 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/mycomputername.local.pid ended
 SUCCESS! 
[2]-  Done                    mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

*kill the other shell window that has the dameon running (just to make sure)*

*now you are good to go! try it:*

```
[root@servert1 ~]#  mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3
Server version: 5.6.10 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

**done!**

Comment: I still get ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: At the stage of changing the root password in the user table: `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'` - from MySQL 5.7 passwords are in authenication_string, so the command is `update user set authentication_string=password('your_root_pw_here') where user='root';`

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps somebody. I was getting the same error, but seemingly for a much different reason than other people.

I have 2 CentOS machines.

I copied my.cnf to the new machine, not realizing that I had upgraded the old machine to MySQL 5.6, and the new machine had 5.5 installed. When I commented out the 5.6-only directives, MySQL started as expected. (and now I am running the upgrade so I can apply the massively useful `innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown` and `innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup` directives)

I would suggest trying a bare minimum my.cnf. If MySQL starts up, then you've found the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a MySQL server installed, there is install packages on mysql's site, or you can install through macports (I assume from the darwin11 line).
I installed mine via ports, and the socket lives in /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I don't got tmp folder setting up right. What I end up with these steps:

```
1. cd /

2. ln -s private/tmp /tmp
```