# Mysql connection error in MAC OS X lion

Tags: mysql, installation

I have tried all the solutions to access mysql that are described before in stackoverflow.
When I type mysql and the terminal asks for  password,when I type password and press enter it says `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

Any idea,this  problem making me crazy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This one works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843731/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-sock-2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're starting the mysql server first. The command is `sudo mysqld_safe`. Also try looking at my.cnf (likely in `/etc/`) and search for "socket". You may need to change the socket location to /tmp/mysql.sock.